# How can I plot the graph based on time from TimeUsed?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

Good day everyone,

Can anyone help me how to plot the result using time from computer. Here, I used timeUSed to generate the time;

```
α = 2*Pi; 
For[t = 0, t < 10, t++, eg = {{1/4, 1/4, (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])}, 
 {1/4, 1/4, (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])}, 
 {(1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), 
  ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])^2, ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])}, 
 {(1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), 
  ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])^2}}; 
 m1 = Det[eg]; t = t + TimeUsed[];
```

I want to Plot m1 versus t (increment by TimeUsed[]).

How can I do the coding for plotting?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do it in a little different way.

```
α = 2*Pi; 
eg[t_] = {{1/4, 1/4, (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])}, 
 {1/4, 1/4, (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])}, 
 {(1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), 
  ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])^2, ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])}, 
 {(1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), 
  ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])^2}}; 

data=Table[Join[{t}, Timing[Det[eg[t]]]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

> {{0, 0.000423, 0}, {1, 0.000459, 0}, {2, 0.000505, 0}, {3, 0.000544, 
>     0}, {4, 0.000489, 0}, {5, 0.000518, 0}, {6, 0.00047, 0}, {7, 
>     0.000387, 0}, {8, 0.000397, 0}, {9, 0.000467, 0}, {10, 0.00046, 0}}

Now you have a list of `{t, time used, det}`. You can choose any two of them and plot them with `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot` like

```
ListPlot[data[[All,{1,2}]]]
```

**Using For**

```
data = {};(*Empty List*)
For[t = 0, t < 10, t++,
 data = Join[{Join[{t}, Timing[Det[eg[t]]]]}, data]]
```

Comment: thank you for helping me but I have a question here: 1. What it mean by Join? 2. In ListPlot, {1,2} represent what value? thank you .

Comment: if there any way to plot by using For loop? Actually, I dont really understand

Comment: 1. `data` is a 3xn array. `data[[All,{1,2}]]` takes all elements at the second and third column. You need to use a two column array for `ListPlot`.

2. `Join[{a},{b,c}]={a, b, c}`.

Comment: thank you. I will test it.

Comment: I want to know either the command Timing is time given by computer system?

Comment: [`Timing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Timing.html) is a mathematica command. If you want to know more about any command, go to Help>Wolfram Documentation and type it. It will show you all details and examples.